# Youtube Data Api : How to add redirect link to each videos from Youtube trending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-data-api

I am working on an app where I display current trending videos on YouTube (thumbnail, video title and channel title) via YoutubeDataApi. I would like to access to the correct URL whenever I click on the thumbnail or the title of a trending video.
This is the code I'm using in my controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController


  def index
    youtube_data_api = YoutubeDataApi.new.client
    @result, @errors = youtube_data_api.list_videos 'snippet, id', chart: 'mostPopular', region_code: 'FR', max_results: '50'
  end
end
```

And this is the code I use in my view:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; padding:20px 0;">
  <% @result.items.each do |video| %>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{video_id}" target="_blank" style="color:black"><img src="<%= video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url %>" height="90" width="120">

      <div id="channel_title">
        <u><b><%= video.snippet.channel_title %></u></b>
      </div>  

      <div id="video_title" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <i><%= video.snippet.title %></i>
      </div>

      </a>
  <% end %>
```

Gem used in this app: gem `'google-api-client', '>0.7'`

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Which gem are you using so we can see what you have to work with a little better.

Just take this with a grain of salt but your image has a src "<%= video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url %>"

Does that url point to the video url? If it does just change your href value to that video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url.

Currently with that href all of your videos will open a new tab to "https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending"

Is there a url on video.snippet (video.snippet.url) ?

Oh also you will need to wrap an  around both the title and the thumbnail so that when you click on them it will link. With your loop you are getting the data for each individual video so if you can get the right url you just need to put links around everything and you should be good.

EDIT:

I think I have the answer for you. You are already sending off to retrieve the id's of the videos to the api so all you have to do to get them is do, `video.id
v=#{video.id} instead of video_id unless you make another variable called that and set it equal to video.id.
in your view loop:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; padding:20px 0;">
  <% @result.items.each do |video| %>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<%= #{video.id} %>" target="_blank" style="color:black"><img src="<%= video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url %>" height="90" width="120">

      <div id="channel_title">
        <u><b><%= video.snippet.channel_title %></u></b>
      </div>  

      <div id="video_title" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <i><%= video.snippet.title %></i>
      </div>

      </a>
  <% end %>
```

So just simply the variable injected in your a href changes from video_id to video.id. However what youtube gives you is simply the video id not the full link, as you already noticed. With that slight ruby variable change you should be good to go! :)

Oh forgot to mention the ruby won't show up unless you throw in an erb like tag like shown above.

A possibly nicer way of doing the same thing would be to do:

```
<%= link_to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{video.id}", style="color: black;", target="_blank", style="color: black;" do %>

.... (stuff you are wrapping)

<% end %>
```

So altogether:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; padding:20px 0;">
      <% @result.items.each do |video| %>
          <%= link_to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=#{video_id}", style="color: black;", target="_blank", style="color: black;" do %>
            <img src="<%= video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url %>" height="90" width="120">

            <div id="channel_title">
              <u><b><%= video.snippet.channel_title %></u></b>
            </div>  

            <div id="video_title" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
              <i><%= video.snippet.title %></i>
            </div>

        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Cheers

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. I edited my post to add which gem I am using ('google-api-client', '>0.7') and also updated my controller in the meantime; I actually deleted the link "https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending" since it is only redirecting to the trending youtube video page instead of opening videos specifically as wanted.
I tried the solution you provided me and unfortunately each link redirects to the URL of each thumbnail. Not there yet but it feels like I'm getting closer thanks to you :)

Comment: Think I got the answer for you just change your video_id to video.id. Hope it works :)  I put a little more in an edited part to my answer.

Comment: Well plus the slight change in string variable interpolation.